# Shared objects linking in Fortran from multiple source files into a single library

Tags: compilation, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran

I'm having problems with linking several Fortran modules/subroutines into a shared library.

The thing is, I first had a standalone Fortran program, with that everything went fine. This consisted of

```
main.f95
mymodule.f95
myutils.f95
```

But now I am adapting things so that I can call the Fortran code from R.

So, I discard the main program main.f95 and I have a new file, let's say

```
callFromR.f95
```

which contains a subroutine that will be called from R. This routine shall use the module `mymodule`, and this module has dependencies on `myutils`.
I compile all three of them as shared objects:

```
gfortran -shared -fPIC callFromR.f95 -o callFromR.so
gfortran -shared -fPIC mymodule.f95 -o mymodule.so
gfortran -shared -fPIC myutils.f95 -o myutils.so
```

Now I somehow need to combine all three of them in a shared object file (not a object file). How can I do this?

(Consequently, when I call the `callFromR` subroutine in R, some subroutines that are located in the `mymodule` code are not found.)

Comment: What does it mean they are not found? Do you import all three .so files or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create object files

```
gfortran -c -fPIC callFromR.f95 -o callFromR.o
gfortran -c -fPIC mymodule.f95 -o mymodule.o
gfortran -c -fPIC myutils.f95 -o myutils.o
```

and then pack them into the library

```
gfortran -shared  callFromR.o  mymodule.o myutils.o -o callFromR.so
```

Comment: That way, the compilation gives undefined references to main...

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In Funktion `_start':
(.text+0x20): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I just forgot the `-c` flag. Many questions and answers here explain that mistake.

Comment: Thanks, it compiles with the dummy example I made.. Going to test if the call from R works later